# Ext4 - Last Write Time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ext4

I'm currently looking at an issue with data loss and was using the tune2fs utility, I was wondering what 'Last write time:' was referring too? The volume is written to constantly and backups confirm that the data that I lost has been backed up, but I just want to understand what that field means as it cant be the last time data was written to disk :)

Thanks,

Martin